# Swift error on Constraints

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm trying to create some Constraints for a button that is moved with the UIPanGestureRecognizer

```
button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

let line = ("\(p.x % snapX)")
let column = ("\(p.x % snapY)")

let constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(line))

let constraint3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: CGFloat(column))

view.addConstraints([constraint2,constraint3])
```

but i have a "could not find member 'CenterX' error

P.s. line and column may take for example the value 27.6666564941406 and 0.666656494140625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the compiler is trying to find CenterX on the wrong enum type. Try using the full enum definition:

```
NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX
```

and

```
NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY
```